# How to check whether correct date format has been provided

Tags: ruby, validation, date

I'm currently working through the Well-Grounded Rubyist and have a question about an exercise that is asking to check whether a date provided is in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' as opposed to 'yy-mm-dd'.

We have a class `Ticket` and should create a `date=` method that checks whether the date provided is in the above mentioned format.

Is `.strftime` correct to use here?

In the end the method should return the date in the correct format and provide an error message for dates in the wrong format, like so:

```
ticket = Ticket.new
ticket.date = "2013-11-12"
=> "2013-11-12"
ticket.date = "13-11-12"
=> "Please submit the date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'."
```

Could someone indicate how I could perform these checks on dates?

Comment: Using a regular expression perhaps.

Comment: "Is .strftime correct to use here?" - no. `strptime`, on the other hand, will get you 90% there, save for some corner cases. For those, I'd preface it with a regex check.

Comment: @SagarPandya: regexes alone won't be enough. They don't know anything about dates and their ranges.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev A sufficiently ridiculous regular expression can, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Check if the string looks like dddd-dd-dd, then split it on "-", map the substrings to integers and provide those to `Date::valid_date?`

Comment: If read verbatim, this seems like a simple question. There's no mention of `Date` objects or the need to check if a string is a valid representation of a date, and there are only two possible date string formats. If that's the case, `valid = str.length ==  10`. Then if `str = "13-11-12"`, `valid = str.len == 10 #=> false`, so the correct string would be `"20" + str" #=> "2013-11-12"`. If we want that to work in future centuries, make that `require 'date'; Date.today.year.to_s[0,2] + str #=> "2013-11-12"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks you're right, taken literally this does the trick for this exercise

Comment: `Date.today.year.to_s[0,2] + str` c'mon @CarySwoveland let future generations make a buck on y2.1k

Comment: @steenslag, too bad we won't be around to witness the "y2.1k" industry and whether that expression (nice!) will be their moniker. I've thought being part of the y2k industry must have been purgatory for coders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Date::xmlschema](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-xmlschema) is strict about this specific format (try this in IRB):

```
  require 'date'

  Date.xmlschema("2013-11-12") #<Date: 2013-11-12 ((2456609j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

  #invalid month number:
  Date.xmlschema("2013-13-12") #<ArgumentError: invalid date>

  # 2 digit year:
  Date.xmlschema("13-11-12")  #<ArgumentError: invalid date>

  # no leap year:
  Date.xmlschema("2013-02-29")  #<ArgumentError: invalid date>
```

Comment: Ohh, nice, TIL.

Comment: @steenslag thank you for the explanation! How exactly would I include this in my code? Something like this? 
`if str == Date.xmlschema("2013-11-12")
   puts str
else
  puts "Error"`

This doesn't evaluate correctly for me.

Comment: @astarisborn This `xmlschema` method trows an exception when something is wrong. The simplest way to rescue this exception is probably `puts  Date.xmlschema("2013-13-12") rescue puts "Error"`.  See @PragyaSriharsh answer for another way.

Comment: I had not seen that method previously. Very handy. Do you know why this method, `strptime` and others respond to invalid strings by raising an exception rather than simply returning `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the error to the user by using begin..rescue

```
require 'date'
begin
  Date.parse("31-02-2010")
rescue => e 
  p "#{e}"  #print your own custom messages and return accordingly
end
```

Also write

> rescue ArgumentError

It will throw By default error

```
ArgumentError (invalid date)
```